# Can not get content with special character URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to get html content from url. I'm follow code in below :

```
function getContentHTML(theUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divcontent").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

If URL is in English(ex : bbc.com,voa.com....),It will be ok,but if url have contain special character, I can not get content.How can I slove?U can test in my URL.

URL : https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E7%A9%BA%E9%9B%A3%E8%BB%8D%E6%96%B9%E5%A4%A7%E6%94%B9%E5%8F%A3-%E7%A2%BA%E5%AF%A6%E6%9C%89%E4%BB%8B%E5%85%A5%E8%88%AA%E7%AE%A1-120050818.html

Answer (score 1):

Special characters are not allowed in the url. You need to encode the special characters. Use encodeURI function available in javascript. Check rfc 1738 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this function to decode urls:

```
  var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(encodedUrl);
```

or

```
 var uri_dec = decodeURI(encodedUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is because `url` is encoded,browser will automatically put some characters in place of special characters in url for example in place of `space in url %20` gets inserted.**

So you have to encode decode url,explained very clearly in there links :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

```
var encodeduri=https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E7%A9%BA%E9%9B%A3%E8%BB%8D%E6%96%B9%E5%A4%A7%E6%94%B9%E5%8F%A3-%E7%A2%BA%E5%AF%A6%E6%9C%89%E4%BB%8B%E5%85%A5%E8%88%AA%E7%AE%A1-120050818.html

 var uri_decoded = decodeURIComponent(encodeduri);  //The decodeURIComponent() function decodes a URI component.

 OR

 var uri_decoded = decodeURI(encodeduri);  //The decodeURI() function is used to decode a URI.
```